# I'm sorting an array by a number property but now I want to apply a second sort using string property. Can I?

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
let array = [
    { name: "Apple", number: "1" },
    { name: "John", number: "2" },
    { name: "Car", number: "1" },
    { name: "Tiger", number: "1" },
    { name: "Jeep", number: "2" },
    { name: "Bee", number: "1" },
    { name: "Zoo", number: "2" },
    { name: "Cow", number: "9" },
    { name: "Pet", number: "6" },
]
```

Right now I sort this array using the number property which results in something like this:

```
let array = [
    { name: "Apple", number: "1" },
    { name: "Car", number: "1" },
    { name: "Tiger", number: "1" },
    { name: "Bee", number: "1" },
    { name: "Zebra", number: "2" },
    { name: "Jeep", number: "2" },
    { name: "Quake", number: "2" },
    { name: "Pet", number: "6" },
    { name: "Cow", number: "9" }, 
]
```

This is done by using this function

```
    sortedByNumber(array){
        return array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
    },
```

I am wondering if it's possible to also sort the array using the name property so that the elements are in alphabetical order while keeping the number ordering as well. The result should look like this:

```
let array = [
    { name: "Apple", number: "1" },
    { name: "Bee", number: "1" },
    { name: "Car", number: "1" },
    { name: "Tiger", number: "1" },
    { name: "Jeep", number: "2" },
    { name: "Quake", number: "2" },
    { name: "Zebra", number: "2" },
    { name: "Pet", number: "6" },
    { name: "Cow", number: "9" },
]
```

Comment: _"Can I?"_ - Yes. Just give it a try...

Comment: As a tip, try to add the sort logic you want to achieve to the same sort function :P

Comment: pick the third answer of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
console.log(array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.number > b.number) return 1;
    if (a.number < b.number) return -1;

    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
}))
```

the result will be like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bee",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Car",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tiger",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jeep",
    "number": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "number": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Zoo",
    "number": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pet",
    "number": "6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cow",
    "number": "9"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [
  { name: "Apple", number: "1" },
  { name: "John", number: "2" },
  { name: "Car", number: "1" },
  { name: "Tiger", number: "1" },
  { name: "Jeep", number: "2" },
  { name: "Bee", number: "1" },
  { name: "Zoo", number: "2" },
  { name: "Cow", number: "9" },
  { name: "Pet", number: "6" }
];

const strCompare = (a, b) => {
  if (b > a) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
};

const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (a.number === b.number) {
    return strCompare(a.name, b.name);
  }
  return Number(a.number) - Number(b.number);
};

array.sort(compare);

console.log(array)
```